# java script internal problrm

Tags: javascript, django

my javascript code doesnt work internal (it works external) what is the problem
i tried external and it worked well but when i add js file to statics in django i can load css with {% load static%} well but my js file doesnt work .

```
    function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {

        var scrollWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollWidth;
        var clientWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).clientWidth;
        $(targetElement).animate({ scrollLeft: scrollWidth - clientWidth },
        {
            duration: speed,
            complete: function () {
                targetElement.animate({ scrollLeft: 0 },
                {
                    duration: speed,
                    complete: function () {
                        animatethis(targetElement, speed);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

      };

       animatethis($('#scroll-div'), 22000);
```

and this is my HTML page :

[image: how i load my file]

when i run my server i can see my js file is loaded

[[image: loaded js file[2]]

i think my problem is is in my js code or some import probs.

Comment: Please include your template.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you placed your js code in an external file and now it's not running on the page. This is likely because you haven't imported the javascript file to load it on the page in a script tag. So inside your javascript block or even inside a content block, you need something like:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/folder/file.js' %}"></script>
```

where `js` is the name of the folder inside of your static folder that stores your javascript, `folder` is a folder (if you have one) that further organizes your code and might be multiple paths deep if you have many nested folders, and of course `file.js` is the name of your file. If you just have a `js` folder and no subfolders, the path would be `js/file.js`.

Answer (score 0):

i found soloution ,my problem was in priority of jquery  before my file script.